# Speed up distance calculations, sliding window

Tags: python, algorithm, fft, sliding-window

I have two time series A and B. A with length `m` and B with length `n`. `m << n`. Both have the dimension `d`.

I calculate the distance between A and all subsequencies in B by sliding A over B. 
In python the code looks like this.

```
def sliding_dist(A,B)
    n = len(B)
    dist = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n-m):
        subrange = B[i:i+m,:]
        distance = np.linalg.norm(A-subrange)
        dist[i] = distance
    return dist
```

Now this code takes a lot of time to execute and I have very many calculations to do. 
I need to speed up the calculations. My guess is that I could do this by using convolutions, and multiplication in frequency domain(FFT). However, I have been unable to implement it.

Any ideas? :) Thanks

Comment: This question is about optimizing code. Those questions belong here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can indeed use FFTs to speed up convolutions via the frequency domain.  However, you don't have a convolution here.

Comment: Well, not at the current implementation. Wouldn't it be possible to rewrite the problem to an equivalent convolution though?

Comment: Have you tried creating a super-A that is just a concatenation of copies of A of length `n`, so that you only have to do a single subtraction and a single call to `norm()`? Not sure what exactly is the bottleneck. Can you specify the order of magnitude for `n` and `m`?

Comment: m  ~ 10, n ~ 500

Comment: It is always good optimization to represent algorithm in matrix form, to have as less as possible numpy calls. I think this can be done with 2*m+1 numpy calls. One that set d=numpy.square(A[0]*B[:-m]). Than m-1 calls that adds d+=numpy.square(A[i]*B[i:-m+i]). And numpy.sqrt(d, out=d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementation with matrix operations, like I mentioned in the comment. Idea is to evaluate norm step by step. In your case i'th value is:

```
d[i] = sqrt((A[0] - B[i])^2 + (A[1] - B[+1])^2 + ... + (A[m-1] - B[i+m-1])^2)
```

First three lines calculate sum of squares, and last line is doing sqrt().

Speed-up is ~60x.

```
import numpy
import time

def sliding_dist(A, B):
    m = len(A)
    n = len(B)
    dist = numpy.zeros(n-m)
    for i in range(n-m):
        subrange = B[i:i+m]
        distance = numpy.linalg.norm(A-subrange)
        dist[i] = distance
    return dist

def sd_2(A, B):
    m = len(A)
    dist = numpy.square(A[0] - B[:-m])
    for i in range(1, m):
        dist += numpy.square(A[i] - B[i:-m+i])
    return numpy.sqrt(dist, out=dist)

A = numpy.random.rand(10)
B = numpy.random.rand(500)
x = 1000
t = time.time()
for _ in range(x):
    d1 = sliding_dist(A, B)
t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(x):
    d2 = sd_2(A, B)
t2 = time.time()

print numpy.allclose(d1, d2)
print 'Orig %0.3f ms, second approach %0.3f ms' % ((t1 - t) * 1000., (t2 - t1) * 1000.)
print 'Speedup ', (t1 - t) / (t2 - t1)
```

**Update**

This is 're-implementation' of norm you need in matrix operations. It is not flexible if you want some other norm that [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) offers. Different approach is possible, to create matrix of B sliding windows and make norm on that whole array, since norm() receives parameter axis. Here is implementation of that approach, but speed-up is ~40x, which is slower than previous.

```
def sd_3(A, B):
    m = len(A)
    n = len(B)
    bb = numpy.empty((len(B) - m, m))
    for i in range(m):
        bb[:, i] = B[i:-m+i]
    return numpy.linalg.norm(A - bb, axis=1)
```

Comment: This is great! Could you give an explanation to why this work? :) I'm not completely following.

Comment: @CarlRynegardh I added some comments. I hope it is enough :-)

Comment: sd_3 can be implemented using [numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html).

Answer (score 6):

`norm(A - subrange)` isn't a convolution in itself, but it may be expressed as:

```
sqrt(dot(A, A) + dot(subrange, subrange) - 2 * dot(A, subrange))
```

How to calculate each term fast:

- `dot(A, A)` - this is just a constant.
- `dot(subrange, subrange)` - this can be calculated in O(1) (per position) using a recursive approach.
- `dot(A, subrange)` - this **is** a convolution in this context.  So this can be calculated in the frequency domain via the [*convolution theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).<sup>1</sup>

Note, however, that you're unlikely to see a performance improvement if the subrange size is only 10.

---

<sub>1. AKA [*fast convolution*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fast%20convolution%22).</sub>

Comment: Idea of calculating norm() with dot()'s probably gains improvement.